# Why does Javascript creates cookie after php function starts to run even if the one is first in order

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a question about an order in code. I wanted to create a cookie with a language, and then use the function l to translate. This is the code:

```
<script>
var lang = navigator.language;
if (document.cookie.indexOf("LANG=")==-1) {
    if (lang=="pl"||lang=="en-US") {
        document.cookie = "LANG="+lang+";domain=xxx;path=/";
    } else {
        document.cookie = "LANG=en-US;domain=xxx;path=/";
    }
}
</script>
<?php

include 'translations.php';


function l($t) {
    global $trsl;
    $l = $_COOKIE['LANG'];
    if ($l=="en-US") {
        return $t;
    } else {
        return $trsl[$l][$t];
    }
}
?>
```

The problem that I find when I enter the website is that when you enter for the first time, it shows me an error saying that the requested cookie is not defined. But when I press Ctrl+F5 everything goes back to normal. I guess that the php code loads before the js code, but why is that? Is there some way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mean enter the website, you mean load the script for the first time?

You are confused about where each script is processed. Javascript as you write it is mean to load up and processed on the browser, while the php will be run on the host machine. So you php will be triggered and running before the whole thing is loaded up in the browser. hence the error.

If you are confused and want to know how it happen, trigger up chrome dev tools and swith to tab network. Then open the page and see header part of the request (make sure its show all / html). Then push f5 and compare from before. You will see that cookie header is assigned on the second request.

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: Alright, that explains a lot, but is there a way to prevent it? And make the cookie before php will try to get the one?

Comment: You could separate your script. Create html that create those cookies with javascript inside. Then do some action to go to the php side. Or in php do some existence checking pf the cookies and just made them on php with set_cookie or directly assign the $_COOKIE var